# Reading an unknown number of lines with some empty ones

Tags: python, input

I need to read an unknown number of lines from console, but there's some empty ones in there and I need to read them as well.
Here's how I was trying to do

```
    while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
        if line:
            text.append(line)
        else:
            break
    except (EOFError):
        break
```

But It'll stop at the first blank line. Any idea how to solve that? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use an if-else condition if you need to append empty ones. Simply use `text.append(raw_input())` in try block without if-else.

Comment: Are you reading lines typed in the console by a user, or are you reading lines piped to your `stdin` from another program? If it's the latter, just get rid of the `break` and read until you hit `EOF`. If it's from the user, then your problem is not solvable in code, unless you can write code to read the user's mind to know when he's done typing.

Comment: huh, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: The second option. Got rid of break and if/else and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to allow blank lines as valid input, there is then no point to test if a line is blank at all with `if line:`. A `try` block that catches `EOFError` would be enough. In Windows, `EOF` can be generated with Ctrl-Z, while in Linux, it can be generated with Ctrl-D.

```
text = []
while True:
    try:
        text.append(raw_input('> '))
    except EOFError:
        break
print(text)
```